# iOS10: Some UICollectionViewCells z-ordered above SectionHeader / SectionFooter?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, ios10

In two separate controllers, I am seeing a strange behavior where *some* UICollectionViewCells have a higher z-index than the sticky SectionHeader or SectionFooter. It becomes evident when I scroll the UICollectionView and some cells pass over the header/footer and some pass under (expected).

To make things more confusing, it's only some cells, not all of them. It seems to only happen after a reloadSections call. I'm stumped.

I am certain this wasn't happening in iOS9.

In the image below, you can see the two UICollectionViewCells (James / Chrys) and in between them is the SectionFooter. So, one cell is somehow z-ordered above, and the other is below.
[image]

**Update**: After examining the view hierarchy of the UICollectionView, I noticed after reloadSections was called for the 3rd time, some UICollectionViewCells started to be placed above the SectionHeader in the view hierarchy and the SectionHeader now has alpha=0 and hidden=YES, which I never set myself.

```
<MyProject.SectionHeaderCell: 0x7fd831420c50;  baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 552; 375 36);  text = 'HEADER TITLE TEXT'; alpha = 0; hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000043f7a0>>
```

**Update** I am pretty suspect of iOS10 having broken the reloadSections call. I am using this awful workaround to fix the problem for now:

```
for view in _collectionView!.subviews {
  if view is SectionHeaderCell {
    _collectionView?.addSubview(view)
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share screenshot and related code ?

Comment: Added an image! There are so many codepaths involved in UICollectionViews, what in particular would you want to look at?